# How can I autoplay multiple songs in the background on an HTML page?

Tags: html

I am using background audio autoplay in my HTML page, but I want to have another song start as soon as the previous one finishes without any intervention from the user.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
<div id="audioplayer" data-autoplay="loop">
    <audio data-src="wp-content/preview.mp3"></audio>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the rest of the code?

Comment: Take a look at `onended`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var pt = "wp-content/";
var songs = ["preview", "first_audio", "second_audio", "tree_audio", "other_audio"],
audio = document.getElementById("player");
audio.addEventListener("ended", function() {
    var getAudio = this.getAttribute("data-src"),
        getPos = songs.indexOf(pt + getAudio);
    audio.src = pt + songs[getPos + 1];
    audio.play();
});
```